# Use of "to" in "updates to come"/"more to follow"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, infinitive-constructions

I'm confused by the construction of "Noun + to infinitive". Is it short for "Noun is + to infinitive?" "Updates to come" becomes "update is to come". "More to follow" becomes "more is to follow". Is my understanding right?

> Jon Dahl Tomasson will be speaking to local media and RoversTV ahead
> of tomorrow's home clash with Bristol City.
>
> **Updates to come**./ **More to follow**.

[twitter](https://twitter.com/Rovers/status/1565686396618170368?s=08)

Comment: Quotes must always be attributed.

Comment: You have it right.

Comment: ...except that it's 'Updates are to come'.

Comment: @KateBunting What does "to" mean in "Updates to come" or "More to follow?"

Comment: I thought you said you understood it! If something _is to_ happen, it is expected or planned that it will happen.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why "is" is dropped?

Comment: _To_ in short talk (no sentences, like headlines, notes, etc) followed by an infinitive is short for _is/are to_, the future schedule construction. _Be_ is often deleted when it's predictable.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you can treat these utterances as an example of *zero copula*, or the omission of the verb *to be* in situations where it is not required for comprehension. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_copula#In_English) notes, this often appears in headlines ("Parliament [is] at a standstill") or other contexts where brevity is important, like on Twitter or in an advertisement.

So in this reading, readers know to connect the two ideas as if the copula was there:

> updates [are] to come
>
> more [is] to follow.

That said, you might encounter strings like *more to follow* in other contexts that don't need to be explained through a copula. For instance, take this sentence:

> So far, we have made six cheeses, with **more to follow**, which we'll write about on [URL]. (Margo True, *[The One-Block Feast](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_One_Block_Feast/inlgYOatTYgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22with%20more%20to%20follow%22&pg=PA117&printsec=frontcover)*, 2011,  p. 117).

Since the item is part of a prepositional phrase, it makes sense without inserting the copula. Indeed, one could play around with this phrasing and end up omitting the preposition:

> We have made six cheeses. More to follow.

If you saw that without seeing the previous example, you may not know whether a preposition or a copula was omitted. That's okay; either way you explain it through reconstruction, *more to follow* works to communicate that more cheeses will be made.

Comment: I'd prefer 'omission of the verb _be_ ...' in the first sentence. Here, _be-deletion_ rather than _to be-deletion_ is used. 'He was thought [to be] irresponsible' shows _to be-deletion_.

Answer (score 0):

> Updates to come./ More to follow.

There are updates that are to/will come./ There is more [of what you have just seen/heard] that are to/will follow.

**to come** and **to follow** act adjectivally.